# How to monitor my own private fd using D-bus?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ipc, dbus

> I have some doubt when taking D-bus IPC into my client program.
>
> In my opinion, D-bus has its own way to manage the low-level socket.
> The socket fd is packed into a 'DBusConnection', and then be used to communicate with daemon, write/read/dispatch/loop. That's ok.
>
> But if the client needs to directly monitor/select another socket, such as monitor a tcp port, using its own way sometimes.
> Is D-bus fit for this situation ? How could I select the two sockets at the time when using with D-bus ?
> Is D-bus designed to communicate with other local processes only via 'DBusConnection' connecting with daemon ?
>
> I just start to use D-bus, and really confused.
> Any help will be appreciated ~

Sorry I did not present it clearly.
I'll take with an example to detail it.

Some guys familiar with D-bus may have looked up the source code of 'dbus-monitor', one tool attached to D-bus.
'dbus-monitor' uses '*dbus_bus_get*' to create a connection with daemon,
and then call '*dbus_connection_get_object_path_data*' to tell dameon which objects it support, and so forth( sth not cared here ),
finally, '*_dbus_loop_run*' for main loop.

With curiosity, I have done some diving work about the implementations of these D-bus APIs. ( It's not enough obviously. )
From my point of view, same with the usual IPC logic, the essential work of these steps looks like (May be it's not quite sure.) :  open a local socket, connect to the server(daemon), read/write/select (the server uses epoll) socket fd.

Ok, thanks for your patience. fine~

In order to communicate with daemon, D-bus creates a socket and uses its own way(API) to manipulate the socket. ( the socket fd is encapsulated into
D-bus's connection structure -- '*DBusConnection*', we can NOT directly operate it. )

Now my question is if I need D-bus to create a '*DBusConnection*' (encapsulate a local socket fd) to talk to the daemon, like 'dbus-monitor'.
And at the same time, my client application also needs to create another socket fd to monitor a tcp port.
I wonder whether there is a way to simultaneously 'select' these two kind of socket fd? ( one encapsulated in D-bus's connection structure
which can NOT be select explicitly, another is a general socket fd. )

Comment: Need people in the new documentation section instead of putting stuff on hold. On topic: dbus is an inter-process communication method. I was using it without thinking about any sockets or descriptors... It is more about objects, functions and arguments.

Comment: Call [dbus_connection_set_watch_functions](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusConnection.html#gaebf031eb444b4f847606aa27daa3d8e6), get some DBusWatch, then you can select.